# Update columns in dataframe inside panel without for loop?

Tags: pandas

I wrote the function below to create 3 columns inside a panel (all dataframes).
The for loop is for updating their value based on a calculation.

Is there any way to update those columns, for all dataframes, without using a for loop?

```
def addAdjustedColumns(symbols, quotes):
    new_quotes = quotes.copy()

    # add 3 columns to all dataframes inside the panel
    new_quotes = quotes.transpose(2, 0, 1)
    new_quotes['AdjOpen'] = 0.
    new_quotes['AdjHigh'] = 0.
    new_quotes['AdjLow'] = 0.
    new_quotes = new_quotes.transpose(1, 2, 0)    

    for symbol in symbols:
        new_quotes[symbol].AdjOpen = new_quotes[symbol].Open * (new_quotes[symbol].AdjClose / new_quotes[symbol].Close)
        new_quotes[symbol].AdjHigh = new_quotes[symbol].High * (new_quotes[symbol].AdjClose / new_quotes[symbol].Close)
        new_quotes[symbol].AdjLow = new_quotes[symbol].Low * (new_quotes[symbol].AdjClose / new_quotes[symbol].Close)

    return new_quotes
```

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some panel operations that you might find helpful. I organize the panel such that (in your parlance), the symbols (A to D) are the minor_axis and the fields (High,Low,Close) are the items, while the dates are the major_axis. These are all under pandas 0.12

```
In [12]: p = tm.makePanel()

In [13]: p.items = ['High','Low','CLose']

In [14]: p
Out[14]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: High to CLose
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

Field operations are broadcast for all symbols across dates easily

```
In [15]: p['HL'] = p['High']-p['Low']

In [16]: p
Out[16]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 4 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: High to HL
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

To add a symbol, transpose, add and transpose back

```
In [17]: pa = p.transpose(2,0,1)

In [18]: pa
Out[18]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 4 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 30 (minor_axis)
Items axis: A to D
Major_axis axis: High to HL
Minor_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00

In [19]: pa['E'] = pa['A'] + pa['D']

In [20]: p = pa.transpose(1,2,0)

In [21]: p
Out[21]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 4 (items) x 30 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: High to HL
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 to 2000-02-11 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to E
```

Comment: these are all inherently slow operations because you are doing lots of little indexing operations. instead it is much more efficient to either construct a panel directly from a multi level dict or concat frames. if you have lots of symbols then creating as new (rather than modifying) will be much faster

Comment: When I tested with only 2 symbols mine was faster, but then I did it  with several symbols and your solution was faster. Thanks.